# Local SMTP server for ubuntu

Tags: java, authentication, ubuntu, smtp

I'm using a Java class that sends mails using JavaMail. I really need to use it even though authentication is not yet implemented. Basically it just has SMTP hostname, port, from, to, subject and body.

I need a SMTP server for it. Most of the ones I've tried use authentication.
Does anyone know maybe a local smtp server for ubuntu?
It doesn't have to be very complex/secure because it's just a proof of concept.

Something like sending a text email from my gmail account to my yahoo account. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Postfix? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

Comment: I have managed to use one of Google's smtp servers. thanks for the response though